# How does induction work when a body is charged (ie) not neutral?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I know that for a neutral body, if a point charge is placed next to it, induction works something like this:

[image]

Consider a uniformly charged conducting body with charge Q on it. We place a positive point charge q1 near it. Do the positive charges on the conducting sphere become denser away from the point charge and less dense near the point charge?

[image]

Comment: In the second scenario, is the sphere made of (even slightly) conductive material or out of an (at least nearly) ideal insulator? (Meaning, are you sure it will stay **uniformly** charged when you move another charge nearby)

Comment: Sorry for the confusing diagram, the uniformly charged condition is before the new point charge was introduced. Am I right in thinking that the charge will become non uniform on the conductor when the point charge is introduced?

Comment: Yes, the posted answer is correct.

Comment: @ThePhoton thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes 
Because field inside the conducting shell should be zero
Initially due to uniform charge the net field was zero
When we introduce a charge outside to overcome the change inside, the charge density becomes non uniform and decreases near the charge